# Charging my laptop with a universal adapter

Tags: battery-charging, adapter

My laptop charger's adapter recently died, and as a new one of its kind was very expensive, I got a universal one for free ([here](http://nix.dn.ua/catalogue/13/60/10524/good-1211149.html?brand=HQ-Tech) is the model, I couldn't find a link in English though). The charger's output voltage is variable (12, 15, 16, 18, 19, 20, 24V), and my battery says 14.4 V on it, so I figured I should go for the 15V setting. What I found really weird was that it didn't charge when plugged in. I tried 16V, to no avail. Only when I cranked it up to 18V did it say that it was charging. Can someone here offer an explanation for this very weird behaviour?

If you want a photo of *exactly* what it says on the back of the adapter and/or my battery, please tell me and I'll upload one.

EDIT: If it's relevant, my machine is [this ASUS gaming laptop](http://www.asus.com/ROG_ROG/G55VW/).

Comment: Why not look at the back of the old power adapter to find the correct output voltage?  19V is a very common laptop power supply value.

Comment: Sadly, I don't have the old adapter with me at the moment. But still, if it is 19, why does the battery say 14.4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using your link, I found the specifications for your laptop.  The AC adapter is rated at 19 volts DC output.  That is why you had to increase the voltage on your universal adapter.  Usually, the adapter provides a higher voltage than the battery to insure that it will provide current to the battery.  Also, there is probably circuitry in your laptop to control the charging current and monitor the battery voltage so the battery won't be damaged by overcharging.

Comment: But why doesn't a 14.4V battery charge at 15 or 16V?

Comment: @Bluefire Because the battery management circuitry within the laptop is not designed to support charging at 15 or 16V.